# Powershell GUI for users to call functions

Tags: powershell

I want the user to be able to select the functions they want to run and then click a button to see the output.

I have it working for most of my functions, but some of them don't seem to complete. I basically create an array with the names of all the functions they select and then use a `ForEach` loop to go through running each one they choose.

The weird thing is some of my functions don't seem to do anything, yet if I type them into a powershell console they work fine.

[Screenshot of my Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgmES.png)

Here is the code for the "Run Selected" button:

```
$RunSelectedButton_Click = {
    Import-Module SHB_Testing_Module 

    [array]$SelectedFunctions = @()

    If ($ActiveClientCheck.Checked -eq $true) {$SelectedFunctions += "ActiveClientCheck"}
    If ($ClientSoftwareCheck.Checked -eq $true) {$SelectedFunctions += "ClientSoftwareCheck"}
    If ($CrashControlKeyCheck.Checked) {$SelectedFunctions += "CrashControlKeyCheck"}
    If ($DiskCheck.Checked) {$SelectedFunctions += "DiskCheck"}
    If ($DriverCheck.Checked) {$SelectedFunctions += "DriverCheck"}
    If ($GPOCheck.Checked) {$SelectedFunctions += "GPOCheck"}
    If ($ListInstalledSoftware.Checked) {$SelectedFunctions += "ListInstalledSoftware"}
    If ($ListMSHotfix.Checked) {$SelectedFunctions += "ListMSHotfix"}
    If ($MSOfficePatchCheck.Checked) {$SelectedFunctions += "MSOfficePatchCheck"}
    If ($PDFDefaultSoftwareCheck.Checked) {$SelectedFunctions += "PDFDefaultSoftwareCheck"}
    If ($SCCMVersionCheck.Checked) {$SelectedFunctions += "SCCMVersionCheck"}
    If ($WebsiteCheck.Checked) {$SelectedFunctions += "WebsiteCheck"}
    If ($RunAllFunctions.Checked) {$SelectedFunctions = @('ActiveClientCheck', 'ClientSoftwareCheck', 'DiskCheck', 'DriverCheck', 'GPOCheck', 'ListInstalledSoftware', 'ListMSHotfix', 'MSOfficePatchCheck', 'PDFDefaultSoftwareCheck', 'SCCMVersionCheck', 'WebsiteCheck')}

    ForEach ($FunctionName in $SelectedFunctions) {
        Write-Host $FunctionName -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Invoke-Expression $FunctionName
        Start-Sleep 10
        Write-Host ""
    }
}

. (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'MainForm.designer.ps1')

$SHBTestingTool.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

I have tried piping the `Invoke-Expression` line to `Out-Null`, and using `&` to call the functions instead of `Invoke-Expression`.

I get the same results with each, it will run most of the functions but some don't work.

The ones that don't will run from the PS console though. Here are the functions that don't want to work:

```
 Function DriverCheck
    {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| Select-Object devicename, driverversion | Where-Object {$_.devicename -like "*"}
    }

   #http://jongurgul.com/blog/installedsoftware/ 
   Function ListInstalledSoftware{
        Param([String[]]$Computers)
        If (!$Computers) {$Computers = $ENV:ComputerName}
        $Base = New-Object PSObject;
        $Base | Add-Member Noteproperty ComputerName -Value $Null;
        $Base | Add-Member Noteproperty Name -Value $Null;
        $Base | Add-Member Noteproperty Publisher -Value $Null;
        $Base | Add-Member Noteproperty InstallDate -Value $Null;
        $Base | Add-Member Noteproperty EstimatedSize -Value $Null;
        $Base | Add-Member Noteproperty Version -Value $Null;
        $Base | Add-Member Noteproperty Wow6432Node -Value $Null;
        $Results =  New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object];

        ForEach ($ComputerName in $Computers){
            $Registry = $Null;
            Try{$Registry = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,$ComputerName);}
            Catch{Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "$($_.Exception.Message)";}

            If ($Registry){
                $UninstallKeys = $Null;
                $SubKey = $Null;
                $UninstallKeys = $Registry.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",$False);
                $UninstallKeys.GetSubKeyNames()|ForEach-Object{
                    $SubKey = $UninstallKeys.OpenSubKey($_,$False);
                    $DisplayName = $SubKey.GetValue("DisplayName");
                    If ($DisplayName.Length -gt 0){
                        $Entry = $Base | Select-Object *
                        $Entry.ComputerName = $ComputerName;
                        $Entry.Name = $DisplayName.Trim();
                        $Entry.Publisher = $SubKey.GetValue("Publisher");
                        [ref]$ParsedInstallDate = Get-Date
                        If ([DateTime]::TryParseExact($SubKey.GetValue("InstallDate"),"yyyyMMdd",$Null,[System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,$ParsedInstallDate)){
                        $Entry.InstallDate = $ParsedInstallDate.Value
                        }
                        $Entry.EstimatedSize = [Math]::Round($SubKey.GetValue("EstimatedSize")/1KB,1);
                        $Entry.Version = $SubKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion");
                        [Void]$Results.Add($Entry);
                    }
                }

                    If ([IntPtr]::Size -eq 8){
                    $UninstallKeysWow6432Node = $Null;
                    $SubKeyWow6432Node = $Null;
                    $UninstallKeysWow6432Node = $Registry.OpenSubKey("Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",$False);
                        If ($UninstallKeysWow6432Node) {
                            $UninstallKeysWow6432Node.GetSubKeyNames()|ForEach-Object {
                            $SubKeyWow6432Node = $UninstallKeysWow6432Node.OpenSubKey($_,$False);
                            $DisplayName = $SubKeyWow6432Node.GetValue("DisplayName");
                            If ($DisplayName.Length -gt 0){
                                $Entry = $Base | Select-Object *
                                $Entry.ComputerName = $ComputerName;
                                $Entry.Name = $DisplayName.Trim();
                                $Entry.Publisher = $SubKeyWow6432Node.GetValue("Publisher");
                                [ref]$ParsedInstallDate = Get-Date
                                If ([DateTime]::TryParseExact($SubKeyWow6432Node.GetValue("InstallDate"),"yyyyMMdd",$Null,[System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,$ParsedInstallDate)){
                                $Entry.InstallDate = $ParsedInstallDate.Value
                                }
                                $Entry.EstimatedSize = [Math]::Round($SubKeyWow6432Node.GetValue("EstimatedSize")/1KB,1);
                                $Entry.Version = $SubKeyWow6432Node.GetValue("DisplayVersion");
                                $Entry.Wow6432Node = $True;
                                [Void]$Results.Add($Entry);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        $Results
    }

    Function ListMSHotfix
    {
        $outputs = Invoke-Expression "wmic qfe list"
        $outputs = $outputs[1..($outputs.length)]


        foreach ($output in $Outputs) {
            if ($output) {
                $output = $output -replace 'y U','y-U'
                $output = $output -replace 'NT A','NT-A'
                $output = $output -replace '\s+',' '
                $parts = $output -split ' '
                if ($parts[5] -like "*/*/*") {
                    $Dateis = [datetime]::ParseExact($parts[5], '%M/%d/yyyy',[Globalization.cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat)
                } elseif (($parts[5] -eq $null) -or ($parts[5] -eq ''))
                {
                    $Dateis = [datetime]1700
                }

                else {
                    $Dateis = get-date([DateTime][Convert]::ToInt64("$parts[5]", 16))-Format '%M/%d/yyyy'
                }
                New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
                    KBArticle = [string]$parts[0]
                    Computername = [string]$parts[1]
                    Description = [string]$parts[2]
                    FixComments = [string]$parts[6]
                    HotFixID = [string]$parts[3]
                    InstalledOn = Get-Date($Dateis)-format "dddd d MMMM yyyy"
                    InstalledBy = [string]$parts[4]
                    InstallDate = [string]$parts[7]
                    Name = [string]$parts[8]
                    ServicePackInEffect = [string]$parts[9]
                    Status = [string]$parts[10]
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function MSOfficePatchCheck
    {
    $a = Get-WmiObject -Class "win32_quickfixengineering"
    Write-Output $a
    }
```

It seems like `Get-WmiObject` is a common theme among them, but some of my functions that do work use that same cmdlet. Again *ALL* the functions work from the PS console but some don't work from the GUI.  Any ideas?

Comment: I would start with some basic troubleshooting. Put in some Write-Host or Out-File statements to make sure the code is running at all and to see if data is being produced in the functions or not.

Comment: It does actually have a Write-Host out put in the While loop and it is outputting the name of the functions that don't run.  Plus the functions run if I just type in the name of the function.  And I get absolutely no error output for the functions that don't run.  At first I thought they just needed more time to complete and so I added the start-sleep line.  Even with that at 30 it still didn't show anything so I figured that wasn't it.  There must be something in the functions themselves.  I will try to add some Write host lines in the function themselves to see if they are doing anything.

Comment: I added some Write-Host lines into the functions and they do show up, so the function appears to be starting, and possibly running it all, but just not giving me the output I get from typing the function name in the PS console.

Comment: I also thought maybe it did not like pipped commands, as all the function that don't work have at least a few pipes.  So I commented out the pipes in the DriverCheck function, but still got no output.  From the console it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend, taking a more direct approach to the problem.

For the sake of a sanity check, separate each of your functions into their own .ps1 file.

Put each of those .ps1 files in the same folder.

Use a simple Get-ChildItem call piped to Out-GridView (as your GUI). 
Pick the desired functions from the OGV and process them in a ForLoop.

```
$RunActions = Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Scripts\*.* | Out-GridView -Title 'Select the action items to run' -PassThru
$RunActions.Fullname | %{ &$_}
```

Here is an article on what I am talking about in more detail.

> Creating a Simplistic GUI Interface with Out-GridView
>   http://mikefrobbins.com/2014/09/11/creating-a-simplistic-gui-interface-with-out-gridview

If they run from that simple approach, then that can be used as a check / pointer / indicator to look at other part of the picture that may be root cause.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will give it a try and post the results!

Comment: I created a different script for each function and using your Get-Child/ GridView idea does allow all the functions to work.  Having finished that test, I think I am even more at a loss as to why it doesn't work from my GUI.  When I have some time(hopefully tonight) I will look over the Mike Robbins link your shared.

Comment: Thanks a lot postanote!  We ended up just using this technique instead of the custom GUI I created.  It is a lot simpler and all the functions run.  Also if we add in new scripts at any point in the future we won't have to change anything to the main script, just add the new script into the folder.